# Stopping people from hijacking a voting system using PHP?

Tags: php

What are some code examples that I can use to stop people from casting votes to give them a higher rating by hacking the php script?

Comment: Uhm, I don't get the question. Surely the script is running on a server that the users don't have access to, right? That is, they shouldn't have access to the actual php script, only be able to call it.

Comment: You will have to go into much, much more detail than that, my friend. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line of defense is a cookie.

Basically, you set the cookie on their machine, and disable voting if it is present.

```
setcookie('cookiename', 'voted=1');

// and later

if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiename']) && $_COOKIE['cookiename'] = "voted=1")
{
     // error
}
```

This gets rid of a database call you might need to make in order to validate their voting. It is a good idea to keep this in place, because it is like caching: the fewers hits to the database the better.

The second line of defense is IP limiting. You basically would check for a IP address log in your database, and see if they voted recently.

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO TABLE (`IP_ADDR`, `TIME`) VALUES("'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'", "'.time().'")');

// and later

$results = mysql_query('SELECT IP_ADDR FROM TABLE WHERE IP_ADDR="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'"');

if(mysql_num_rows($results) != 0)
{
    // error
}
```

Turning your entire script into something along the lines of

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiename']) && $_COOKIE['cookiename'] = "voted=1")
{
     die("You have voted recently.");
}

$results = mysql_query('SELECT IP_ADDR FROM TABLE WHERE IP_ADDR="'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'"');

if(mysql_num_rows($results) != 0)
{
    die("You have voted recently");
}

//Do Voting Stuff Here
vote($_GET['vote']);

// Record the vote.
setcookie('cookiename', 'voted=1');
mysql_query('INSERT INTO TABLE (`IP_ADDR`, `TIME`) VALUES("'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'", "'.time().'")');
```

You'll also have to add in the expiration times and such, but the basic jist of it is there.

Comment: Note: You will probably want to reset the cookie if you find on the database that they have voted recently.

Answer (score 3):

1. Set cookies to already voted users and disallow to vote for some time.
2. Beside cookies protection add ip address protection. Single ip address can vote only one time per some period of time. Good alternative for ip protection is protection by combined scheme (ip+user_agent+...).
3. Ask users to enter captcha when they're doing actions too fast.

Comment: Btw., you don't need to keep whole ip log. Keep log only for last 1 hour - it would be even more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ideas:

1. Use a CAPTCHA
2. Record IP address (in accordance with your privacy policy, of course)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to prevent them from doing this is to have a good user authentication system.  Barring that, you could discourage it by use of cookies and [Captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA).